# Extending RCTConvert to provide custom function types

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to extend and RCTConvert to prove customer arguments for a function?

**Example:**
I want to have a function with `NSSet *` argument type

```
@objc func getItems(ids: NSSet, result: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {

}

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getItems:(NSSet *)items result:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)result)
```

But this code fails with an error:

> Unknown argument type 'NSSet' in method -[HealthKitAPI requestPermission:write:result:]. Extend RCTConvert to support this type.

Comment: a hack -> when exporting a method use `id`  instead of `NSSet`
`RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getItems:(id)items result:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)result)`

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it possible.

Extend RCTConvert type and add a custom type here.
RCTConvert contains many macros that help you to write customer converters

```
@interface RCTConvert (NSSet)

+ (NSSet *)NSSet:(id)json;

@end


@implementation RCTConvert (NSSet)
RCT_CUSTOM_CONVERTER(NSSet *, NSSet, [NSSet setWithArray:json])

@end
```